# Imports break moving from python 3.4 to 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module that works fine in python 3.5+ but not in 3.4. The only possible change that may be effecting it is how circular imports are handled in 3.5+.  I cannot find any circular imports though so there may be something else going on.

```
module/
    module/
        __init__.py

        file_a.py
           from module import settings
           from module.file_b import SomeBClass

           def stuff():
               settings.init()
               stuff = SomeBClass()

           def run():
               stuff()

           def main():
               run()

        file_b.py
            from module.settings import config, properties

            class SomeBClass():
                 ....

        file_c.py
            class SomeClass():
                connect to db...

        settings.py
            from module.file_c import SomeClass

            def init():
                global config
                global properties

                config = SomeClass()
                properties = config.get_it()
```

when running I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/somewhere/module/module/file_b.py", line 11, in <module>
    from module.settings import config, properties
ImportError: cannot import name 'config'
```

I have tried running the module with `python -mv` to see if something gets imported more than once but I cannot see anything alarming.

Anyone have experience dealing with the differences between 3.4 and 3.5+? Does trying to access attributes from globals in the settings.init cause issues?